# Maintaining a roll-backable flow of code in python without extreme identation

Tags: python, flatten, try-finally

I've encountered a situation where I'm working over a piece of code where I command changes on a remote object (that is one I can't duplicate to work over a clone), then ask the remote object for some operation in the new state and revert all the changes I made to it by a sequence of opposite commands.
The problem is that if in the middle of all these changes I encounter an error, I want to be able to roll-back all the changes I made so far.

The best fitting solution that came to my mind is the python try-finally workflow, but it's rather problematic when the sequence of commands is long:

```
try:
    # perform action
    try:
        # perform action
        try: 
            # ...
        finally:
            # unroll
    finally:
        # unroll
finally:
    # unroll
```

This way, the more commands I need the deeper my indentation and nesting goes and the less my code is readable.
I've considered some other solutions such as maintaining a stack where for every command I push a rollback action, but this could get rather complicated, and I dislike pushing bound methods into stacks.
I've also considered incrementing a counter for every action I perform then in a single finally decide on the kind of rollback I want depending on the counter, but again, the maintainability of such code becomes a pain.

Most hits I got on searches for "transactions" and "rollback" were DB related and didn't fit very well to a more generic kind of code...
Anyone has a good idea as to how to systematically flatten this atrocity?

Comment: Why do you dislike the stack method? Seems like a perfectly good way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't [Context Manager objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) and the [with](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement improve the situation? Especially if you can use a version of Python where the with statement supports multiple context expressions, as 2.7 or 3.x. Here's an example:

```
class Action(object):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count
    def perform(self):
        print "perform " + str(self.count)
        if self.count == 2:
            raise Exception("self.count is " + str(self.count))
    def commit(self):
        print "commit " + str(self.count)
    def rollback(self):
        print "rollback " + str(self.count)
    def __enter__(self):
        perform()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_value is None:
            self.commit()
        else:
            self.rollback()

with Action(1), Action(2), Action(3):
    pass
```

You'd have to move your code to a set of "transactional" classes, such as `Action` above, where the action to be performed is executed in the `__enter__()` method and, if this terminates normally, you would be guaranteed that the corresponding `__exit()__` method would be called.

Note that my example doesn't correspond exactly to yours; you'd have to tune what to execute in the `__enter__()` methods and what to execute in the `with` statement's body. In that case you might want to use the following syntax:

```
with Action(1) as a1, Action(2) as a2:
    pass
```

To be able to access the `Action` objects from within the body of the `with` statement.

Comment: Can you give an example of usage?

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty elegant solution...
Though, if I need to perform some intermediate calculations between two actions I'll still need to nest the "with"s right?
BTW, would the syntax be the same for Python 2.6? Or what you meant was single action per "with" before 2.7?

Comment: @immortal: Ideally you have some setup action that you want to be sure it's undone at the end; the setup goes in `__enter__()` and the undo goes in `__exit__()`, where you can also check whether an exception was raised. If you also have things to do in between setup and undo, which do not require being undone, you do them in the `with` body.

Comment: @immortal: Until 2.7 the `with` statement only supported a single context expression, i.e. a single action object.